# Enable remote simulator to windows in VS 2017 professional

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to debug the Xamarin.iOS application in Visual Studio 2017 professional, where I want to see the simulator/output on my windows machine which I am not able to see.

I have checked for the option Enable remote simulator to windows in VS by going below path

> Tools => Options => Xamarin => iOS Settings

but here the option is not available.

As per the below links this option is enabled in all VS editions starting from VS 2017 version 15.5.and my VS 2017 version is 15.5.3, still the option is not visible.

https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/17194163-allow-use-of-remoted-ios-simulator-from-all-editio

https://blog.xamarin.com/whats-new-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/

Am i missing anything here ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the option is not available, it is possible that the remote simulator isn't installed on your PC. You can download the installer from Xamarin Documentation website [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/).

You can also install it via the Visual Studio Installer, by clicking **Modify** on your VS installation, selecting **Individual Components** and then checking the checkbox next to **Xamarin Remoted Simulator** in the **Development activities** section and confirming by the **Modify** button.

Answer (score 1):

When navigating to `Tools > Options > Xamarin`, click on `iOS Settings` under `Xamarin`, and it will be there.

[image]

Comment: Apologizes.. I forgot to mention iOS settings in the path. I have edited the question.

Comment: Oh, no problem. Still strange though. Im running 15.5.4 Enterprise Edition

Comment: The option was not available in professional edition later on its been updated. Any solution/help on this ?